# sorting on a nested object elasticsearch 5.2, error: not of nested type

Tags: sorting, search, elasticsearch, nested

I have a field (propertyScore) which is in my Property model inside the 'review' object.
I would like to sort on this field using elasticsearch sort.

Here is an example of my property:

```
{
"bedrooms": 2,
"bathrooms": 2,
"review": {
           "propertyScore": 20
         },
}
```

On my bedrooms field I execute the search query below:

```
sort: 
   [ '_score',
     { bathrooms: { order: 'desc'} }
]
```

How would I then sort on the score field under my reviews.

I have currently done:

```
sort: 
       [ '_score',
         { propertyScore: { order: 'desc', 
                            nested_path: 'review'} 
         } 
       ]
```

and receive the error:

```
[query_parsing_exception] [nested] nested object under path [review] is not of nested type
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is an issue with your mapping. The "review" property is not of type nested. Hence, when using sort with "nested_path" equal to "review", you are getting this error.

You can either change this mapping or you can change the way you are executing the sort. Just try this:

```
sort: 
 [ '_score',
   { "review.propertyScore": { order: 'desc'} }
 ]
```